# Python Selenium webdriver chrome- OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tkinter

I'm making an HTML editor/interpreter with Python [tkinter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html) and I'm also using [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) in order to open chrome and display the output of the html code above the tkinter window. It will do so when the `run` button is clicked. After I click the `run` button, the browser opens but suddenly closes a second later. And then an error shows up in the console. Here is the error:

```
Exception ignored in: <function Popen.__del__ at 0x0000021819AA1430>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Meirom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1055, in __del__
    self._internal_poll(_deadstate=_maxsize)
  File "C:\Users\Meirom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1457, in _internal_poll
    if _WaitForSingleObject(self._handle, 0) == _WAIT_OBJECT_0:
OSError: [WinError 6] The handle is invalid
```

How do I fix this?
Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, asksaveasfilename
from tkinter import messagebox
import os
from selenium import webdriver

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("HTML Editor")
window.configure(bg="grey")
window.state("zoomed")
title = tk.Label(window, text="HTML Editor", font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 40, "underline"), bg="grey")
title.place(x=400, y=20)
screen_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = window.winfo_screenheight()


def open_file():
    file_path = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("HTML Files", "*.html"), ("All Files", "*.*")])

    if not file_path:
        return

    text_box.delete("1.0", tk.END)
    file_func()

    with open(file_path, "r") as file_read:
        text = file_read.read()
        text_box.insert(tk.END, text)
    window.title(f"HTML Editor - {file_path}")


def save_file():
    file_path = asksaveasfilename(defaultextension="txt", filetypes=[("HTML Files", "*.html"), ("All Files", "*.*")])

    if not file_path:
        return

    with open(file_path, "w") as file_write:
        text = text_box.get(1.0, tk.END)
        file_write.write(text)
    window.title(f"HTML Editor - {file_path}")
    file_func()


def stop_program(driver):
    driver.close()
    stop.pack_forget()


def run_code():
    global screen_width, screen_height
    window_title = window.title()
    index = window_title.index("-") + 2
    window_title = window_title[index::]

    with open(window_title, "w") as path:
        content = text_box.get("1.0", tk.END)
        path.write(content)

    basename = os.path.basename(window_title)
    new_file = open(basename, "w")
    new_file.write(content)
    new_file.close()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\chromedriver.exe")
    new_width = screen_width - 680
    driver.get("file:///" + os.getcwd() + "/" + basename)
    driver.set_window_size(new_width, screen_height)
    driver.set_window_position(680, 0, windowHandle="current")
    stop.pack(padx=50, pady=5)
    stop.configure(command=stop_program(driver))


def get_stringvar(event):
    line = text_box.get("insert linestart", "insert")
    if (line[-1] == ">") and ("<" in line) and "<!DOCTYPE html>" not in line:
        new_line = "</" + line[line.rindex("<") + 1:-1] + ">"
        text_box.insert("insert", new_line)
        text_box.mark_set("insert", f"insert-{len(new_line)}c")
        return "break"


def on_closing():
    if window.title() != "HTML Editor":
        window_title = window.title()
        index = window_title.index("-") + 2
        window_title = window_title[index::]
        file = open(window_title, "w")
        file.write(text_box.get("1.0", tk.END))
    quit()


def file_func():
    frame.pack(side="left", fill="y")
    text_box.pack(side="left", expand=True)
    scroll_bar.pack(side="left", fill="y")
    run_b.pack(padx=50, pady=(100, 5), anchor="n")


create = tk.Button(window, text="Create a new file", width=17, height=3, font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 20),
                   command=save_file)
create.place(x=420, y=200)
open_e = tk.Button(window, text="Open an existing file", width=17, height=3, font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 20),
                   command=open_file)
open_e.place(x=420, y=350)

window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
frame = tk.Frame(window, bd=2, relief="raised")

text_box = tk.Text(window, font=("Flux-Regular", 12), fg="black", undo=True, width=600, height=720)
text_box.bind("<Tab>", get_stringvar)

scroll_bar = tk.Scrollbar(window, command=text_box.yview)

run_b = tk.Button(frame, text="Run", width=6, height=2, bg="white", command=run_code)

text_box.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_bar.set)
stop = tk.Button(frame, bg="red", text="Stop", width=6, height=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix the problem very shortly after I posted this question. I noticed that I forgot to use a `lambda` function in my `stop` button's command, so its command ran without me pressing the button. I only modified the `run_code` function. Updated code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, asksaveasfilename
from tkinter import messagebox
import os
from selenium import webdriver

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("HTML Editor")
window.configure(bg="grey")
window.state("zoomed")
title = tk.Label(window, text="HTML Editor", font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 40, "underline"), bg="grey")
title.place(x=400, y=20)
screen_width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = window.winfo_screenheight()


def open_file():
    file_path = askopenfilename(filetypes=[("HTML Files", "*.html"), ("All Files", "*.*")])

    if not file_path:
        return

    text_box.delete("1.0", tk.END)
    file_func()

    with open(file_path, "r") as file_read:
        text = file_read.read()
        text_box.insert(tk.END, text)
    window.title(f"HTML Editor - {file_path}")


def save_file():
    file_path = asksaveasfilename(defaultextension="txt", filetypes=[("HTML Files", "*.html"), ("All Files", "*.*")])

    if not file_path:
        return

    with open(file_path, "w") as file_write:
        text = text_box.get(1.0, tk.END)
        file_write.write(text)
    window.title(f"HTML Editor - {file_path}")
    file_func()


def stop_program(driver):
    driver.close()
    stop.pack_forget()


def run_code():
    global screen_width, screen_height
    window_title = window.title()
    index = window_title.index("-") + 2
    window_title = window_title[index::]

    with open(window_title, "w") as path:
        content = text_box.get("1.0", tk.END)
        path.write(content)

    basename = os.path.basename(window_title)
    new_file = open(basename, "w")
    new_file.write(content)
    new_file.close()
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\chromedriver.exe")
    new_width = screen_width - 680
    driver.get("file:///" + os.getcwd() + "/" + basename)
    driver.set_window_size(new_width, screen_height)
    driver.set_window_position(680, 0, windowHandle="current")
    stop.pack(padx=50, pady=5)
    stop.configure(command=lambda: stop_program(driver))


def get_stringvar(event):
    line = text_box.get("insert linestart", "insert")
    if (line[-1] == ">") and ("<" in line) and "<!DOCTYPE html>" not in line:
        new_line = "</" + line[line.rindex("<") + 1:-1] + ">"
        text_box.insert("insert", new_line)
        text_box.mark_set("insert", f"insert-{len(new_line)}c")
        return "break"


def on_closing():
    if window.title() != "HTML Editor":
        window_title = window.title()
        index = window_title.index("-") + 2
        window_title = window_title[index::]
        file = open(window_title, "w")
        file.write(text_box.get("1.0", tk.END))
    quit()


def file_func():
    frame.pack(side="left", fill="y")
    text_box.pack(side="left", expand=True)
    scroll_bar.pack(side="left", fill="y")
    run_b.pack(padx=50, pady=(100, 5), anchor="n")


create = tk.Button(window, text="Create a new file", width=17, height=3, font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 20),
                   command=save_file)
create.place(x=420, y=200)
open_e = tk.Button(window, text="Open an existing file", width=17, height=3, font=("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 20),
                   command=open_file)
open_e.place(x=420, y=350)

window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_closing)
frame = tk.Frame(window, bd=2, relief="raised")

text_box = tk.Text(window, font=("Flux-Regular", 12), fg="black", undo=True, width=600, height=720)
text_box.bind("<Tab>", get_stringvar)

scroll_bar = tk.Scrollbar(window, command=text_box.yview)

run_b = tk.Button(frame, text="Run", width=6, height=2, bg="white", command=run_code)

text_box.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll_bar.set)
stop = tk.Button(frame, bg="red", text="Stop", width=6, height=2)

window.mainloop()
```